# Why are these semicolumns in this for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I was just looking at W3schools, and was looking at the "for loops". I saw this code example:

```
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford"];
var i = 0;
var text = "";
for (;cars[i];) {
    text += cars[i] + "<br>";
    i++;
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

I saw these semicolumns in the "for loop", I removed them and tried running it again. And as you expect, I got an error. Why are these semicolumns there? This is the first time I saw this and I'm really curious why these need to be there.

Thanks if you can give me some information about this because I couldn't find anything about it...

Comment: it is like a while loop. loop will continue till array end reached. It means no initialization. It will go till car[i] become false. car[i] will become false when i>=car.length

Comment: @HimanshuArora9419 It will first iterate over the array and after it's done display it?

Comment: The i is declared and initialized outside the for and is incremented inside the block. When car[i] is undefined, the condition will be false and the loop terminates.

Comment: No. I didn't get you. but will try to explain it will iterate and same time keep adding element at index i in array car to  text and increment i by 1

Comment: It is because some developer was too cool to use while loop.

Comment: And this is why you don't go to w3fools. Who on earth uses a `for` loop like that without moving the `i` declaration and the `i++` increment into the `for` statement?!? And that on a site that's supposed to be an ___example___ to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for` **loop** is composed by 3 parts as follows:

The first part initializes the loop; the second decides whether or not to continue the loop, and the third does something at the end of each iteration.

But, each of them is optional.

`for (;cars[i];)` statement is same as

```
while(cars[i]){
    //code
}
```

**Note**: it also exists `for(;;)` which is equivalent to :

```
while(true){ }
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, I usually use "while loops". But this seems like a pretty handy thing that can come good to some of my code. Thanks man!

Answer (score 2):

your code

```
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford"];
var i = 0; // initialized here
var text = "";
for (;cars[i];) {
    text += cars[i] + "<br>";
    i++; // it will handle increment
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

is same as

```
for (var i=0;cars[i];i++) {
    text += cars[i] + "<br>";
}
```

As in your code you have initialized `var i` and incremented within loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (;cars[i];)
```

- First semicolon:
  Usually in for loops we declare a counter. But, here the counter is already defined outside the for loop. So, a empty statement.
- Second semicolon: 
  As soon as the counter `i` exceeds the length of the array, using arr[i] while return undefined which is falsy and the loop will be terminated. Usually after the second semicolon we increment or decrement the counter, but here the counter is incremented in the for loop itself.

The semicolons are there so that we don't get a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

The idea structure of for loop should be:

`for(<init>;<condition>;<operation after each iteration>)`

where as:

**init:** *will be perform once before the loop*

**condition:** *will be checked as truthness to enter every time*

**operation after each iteration:** *will be perform after every iteration*

and they are optional.

For the particular example, **init** operation you are doing before with `var i=0` and **operation after each iteration** you are doing manually as `i++` so it is expected to run properly.